# How to animate the transition created in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created one java script for changing the background of a div continuously after some time intervals. Here is the script for that:

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {
var images = [ "images/bg-a.jpg","images/bg-b.jpg" , "images/bg-c.jpg" ];
var bg_spans = [ "#bg-a","#bg-b","#bg-c" ];
var currentImage = 0;

function changeBackground() {

    $( '#bdy' ).css( { backgroundImage: 'url(' + images[ ++currentImage ] + ')'} );
    for(i=0; i<bg_spans.length; i++ ) {
      if(i==currentImage) {
         $( bg_spans[currentImage]).css ( { background: "#eb5405"} );
         $( bg_spans[currentImage]).css ("border-color","#fff" );
      }
      else {
         $( bg_spans[i]).css ( { background: "#000098"} );
         $( bg_spans[i]).css ("border-color","#000098" );  

      }
    }

    if ( currentImage >= images.length - 1 ) {
        currentImage -= images.length;
    }
}
setInterval( changeBackground, 6000 );  
});
```

I want some animation in it like image should fade in smoothly. And the transition of changing the images after some time intervals should be done smoothly like some type of animation. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link, you can change the transition style
[Owl slider](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/transitions.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: yes but its well known `OWL SLIDER` you can always search for OWL SLIDER even if link page is changed